# Center a circle with a letter in grid cell in ionic4

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

I want that the circle with the letter in it is centered in the grid row.

I set the scss as follows:

```
.numberCircle {
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
}
```

In the html file I do:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row no-padding justify-content-start align-items-start>
      <ion-col ion-item no-lines no-padding text-center>
        <div class="numberCircle">X</div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row >
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col ion-item no-lines no-padding text-center>
        <div class="numberCircle">Y</div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col ion-item no-lines no-padding text-center>
        <div class="numberCircle">A</div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col ion-item no-lines no-padding text-center>
        <div class="numberCircle">B</div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>

</ion-item>
```

The problem is that the numberCircle is not centered in the grid cell and therefore not in the row. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I am not sure how you need it https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-kcrhas Can you point out?

Comment: What should I say more. I clearly said that the circle with the number is not centered in the row colum. Look at your stackblitz.

Comment: Is this how you need? https://prnt.sc/okk8uw

Answer (score 1):

You should have margin auto:

```
.numberCircle {
  width: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

A div defaults to block and when you set a width that's not enough. Setting the side margins to auto should do what you want.

I would also investigate the flex options to see if there is a better, built-in way, but I haven't investigated these myself yet to give you specific advice:

[Flex Container Properties - CSS Utilities - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#flex-container-properties)